# PHP: Encode UTF8-Characters to html entities

Tags: php, html, encoding

I want to encode normal characters to html-entities like

```
a => &#x61;
A => &#x41;
b => &#x62;
B => &#x42;
```

but

```
echo htmlentities("a");
```

doesn't work. It outputs the normal charaters (a A b B) in the html source code instead of the html-entities.

How can I convert them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a function for this fairly easily using [mb_ord](https://www.php.net/mb_ord) or [IntlChar::ord](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intlchar.ord.php), either of which will give you the numeric value for a Unicode Code Point.

You can then convert that to a hexadecimal string using [base_convert](https://www.php.net/base_convert), and add the '&#x' and ';' around it to give an HTML entity:

```php
function make_entity(string $char) {
    $codePoint = mb_ord($char, 'UTF-8'); // or IntlChar::ord($char); 
    $hex = base_convert($codePoint, 10, 16);
    return '&#x' . $hex . ';';
}
echo make_entity('a');
echo make_entity('€');
echo make_entity('');
```

---

You then need to run that for each code point in your UTF-8 string. It is **not** enough to loop over the string using something like `substr`, because PHP's string functions work with individual bytes, and each UTF-8 code point may be multiple bytes.

One approach would be to use a regular expression replacement with a pattern of `/./u`:

- The `.` matches each single "character"
- The `/u` modifier turns on Unicode mode, so that each "character" matched by the `.` is a whole code point

You can then run the above `make_entity` function for each match (i.e. each code point) with [preg_replace_callback](https://php.net/preg_replace_callback).

---

Since preg_replace_callback will pass your callback an array of matches, not just a string, you can make an [arrow function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php) which takes the array and passes element 0 to the real function:

```
$callback = fn($matches) => make_entity($matches[0]);
```

So putting it together, you have this:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/./u', fn($m) => make_entity($m[0]), 'a€');
```

---

Arrow functions were introduced in PHP 7.4, so if you're stuck on an older version, you can write the same thing as a regular [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php):

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/./u', function($m) { return make_entity($m[0]) }, 'a€');
```

Or of course, just a regular named function (or a method on a class or object; see [the "callable" page in the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) for the different syntax options):

```
function make_entity_from_array_item(array $matches) {
    return make_entity($matches[0]);
}
echo preg_replace_callback('/./u', 'make_entity_from_array_item', 'a€');
```

Comment: I still don't understand the last line. It breaks for $char = "äöüß", if I call the function via: for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($char); $i++) {
  $result .= self::make_entity(substr($char, $i, 1));
 }

Comment: @User123456789 Yes, substr() works with a single **byte** of the string, it doesn't know about UTF-8, where a single **code point** takes multiple bytes to represent; that's why I suggested preg_replace_callback. See updated answer.

Comment: What does "fn($m) => make_entity($m[0])" mean? If I copy the code, it says "syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)". I also tried "self::make_entity($m[0])" since I copied it into a class and thus changed the function to static. But then it says "undefined variable m". The example in the php documentation says e.g.: "next_year" as function without fn($m) =>

Comment: @User123456789 Ah, that's just an "arrow function", a concise way to write simple anonymous functions introduced in PHP 7.4. If you're stuck on an older version, you can just use a different syntax; I've added some more explanation.